# Ubuntu 20.04LTS not waking up properly after suspend

Tags: drivers, suspend, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce, wakeup

I have a laptop Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H, using a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile. In the Additional Drivers section, I've tried many versions of the driver (eg: nvidia-driver-470, nvidia-driver-495, etc) and the problem remains the same.

The problem is that after I suspend my laptop and later try to wake it up, the screen remains dark, even though the keys in the keyboard light up.

What is weirder is that I connected a second monitor to my laptop through HDMI cable, and the second monitor lights up. I even put my password in the dark, and the laptop unlocks and I can use the second monitor, and the primary screen of the laptop stays dark.
After a closer look, I found out that the primary screen is not completely black, but is just extremely dark.

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux world, so you guys need more details about my hardware, I can edit the question and give these informations to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *primary screen is not completely black, but is just extremely dark* If so try increasing brightness using the dedicated keys.